# Looping through SQL Server table, running stored procedure for the row, and put results in to a table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SQL Server stored procedure for getting an employee's clocked hours over a few days. The procedure uses a card code value for getting the information about the employee.

What I want to do is select all of the `CardCodes` from one table, then loop through each record running the stored procedure and then making a table with the results of each one. so by the end there will be one table with each employees worked times.

Query for getting the list of `CardCodes`:

```
SELECT     
    CardCode
FROM
    CHINA_VISION_PubCards
```

The produces a list like this.

```
007b7aaf
00cf77b6
00cf9200
00cf9f40
007B6FFB
00d398dd
00cf4673
```

And so on.

I can run the stored procesdure inside SQL Server like this.

```
EXEC [dbo].[getPast5DaysWorkedHours] @CardCode = N'007da097'
```

Where `007da097` is the employee's card code.

This produces a result like this:

```
Employee Name | CardCode  |  Clock No  | Date   |  Seconds |  Time  
     Name       007da097      005718    2015.10.16  28761   07:59:21
     Name       007da097      005718    2015.10.21  28991   08:03:11
     Name       007da097      005718    2015.10.23  29768   08:16:08
     Name       007da097      005718    2015.10.28  29441   08:10:41
```

To reiterate what I am trying to do: I want to loop through the list of card codes, and for each one of them run the stored procedure with the `cardCode` value. And then put the results of each procedure call into one table.

Comment: Better change your stored procedure to expect @CardCode as TVP([table valued parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx)) and allow multiple input. Using loop for it is very inefficient

Comment: See demo in link. Very easy create type, alter procedure to allow TVP, change logic a bit, populate argument and call sp :)

Comment: However, to do what you were asking, you would use a cursor.   Google `SQL CURSOR` for tons of examples.

Comment: But don't actually use a cursor. There's no need to.

Comment: Can you select a correct answer?

Answer (score 6):

SQL has while loop

[While Loop T-SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx)

You can do somthing like this. (Untested)

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TempDB..#TEMP') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TEMP
SELECT  distinct  CardCode
INTO #TEMP
FROM CHINA_VISION_PubCards

WHILE ( (select count(*) FROM #TEMP) > 0 )
    BEGIN
         DECLARE @CardCode varchar(50)
         SELECT TOP 1 @CardCode=CardCode FROM #TEMP

         INSERT INTO TableTarget
         EXEC [dbo].[getPast5DaysWorkedHours] @CardCode

         DELETE FROM #TEMP WHERE CardCode = @CardCode
    END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [WHILE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178642.aspx) loop to go through every entry, without using a cursor or repeated SELECT and DELETEs:

```
DECLARE @store table (id bigint identity(1,1), CardCode (your cardcode column type here))

insert into @store (CardCode)
SELECT DISTINCT     
    CardCode
FROM
    CHINA_VISION_PubCards

declare @idx bigint = 1
declare @max bigint = (select MAX(id) from @store)

WHILE @idx<=@max
BEGIN
EXEC [dbo].[getPast5DaysWorkedHours] @CardCode = (select top 1 CardCode from @store where id = @idx)

set @idx = @idx+1

END
```

The comments are right, though - it's a lot nicer if you can use a table-valued parameter to pass through a set of values.